# i want to do a loop start and end due to various range of cells have the same value

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet of payed orders, i want excel to sum total price of items sold which have the same order number

Number of Items varies sometimes there is one item in one order, sometimes there is 3 or more, how can i make excel know number of items with the same order number and calculate order price ?
[Simple Example of a sheet that i'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eikVK.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? You are not showing any effort.

Comment: try looking up SUMPRODUCT function and modify your question if you have any question